# Alternative to qTip2

Tags: jquery, popover, qtip2

Does anyone know a good alternative to qTip2's tooltip.  I really like qTip2 tooltip but it is 40KB compare to jqueryTools.  I am only looking very lightweight popover functionality, where I can add my own CSS style.

I looked into bootstap's popover but it does not offer what qTip2 is offering.  I also want to keep my HTML clean as much as possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at 

http://projects.nickstakenburg.com/tipped (has a small fee though)

http://visionwidget.com/jquery-tooltip-plugins.html

A search for tooltip 2013 is a great way to find the newest plugins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah,There are plenty of them:

**[Simpletip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip)**

**[nextmsg](https://code.google.com/p/next-msg)**

and this link:

**[50 jquery tooltip plugins](http://www.smashingapps.com/2011/12/05/50-awesomely-useful-yet-free-jquery-tooltip-plugins.html)**